# Why can't we easily enlarge images embedded on questions?

Tags: feature-request

See [Compilation succeeded even though there were some errors from Roslyn Diagnostic Analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113987/compilation-succeeded-even-though-there-were-some-errors-from-roslyn-diagnostic) for example:

I always have to right-click and then 'Open image in new tab'. Why can't we just click on the image to see the actual size?

Comment: Generally speaking, users shouldn't be posting such huge but meaningless screenshots, *or* they should link them explicitly.

Comment: I don't think it's meaningless in this particular case. Especially when pertaining to a pretty new technology (Roslyn).

Comment: A cutout of the red squiggles and a text copy of the console wasn't enough?

Comment: Perhaps. But since the question is all about Visual Studio and Roslyn integration, it may add some context.

Comment: Solution: Buy a larger monitor. That image is only 1,366 pixels wide, there are (expensive) [options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution) available.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I do have a wide-screen and still need to enlarge the image. Since the main DIV of StackOverflow is 980px wide, the embedded image width cannot exceed 640px anyway. That's why we need an option to enlarge simply by clicking it.

Comment: @haim, or you could remove the `max-width: 640px` style rule, either from the console or from a custom style (although the results are not always pretty).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, lol. I already mentioned enlarging the image by opening it in a new tab. I want to spare that right-click by simply clicking once to enlarge. Messing with the console is obviously longer than what i'm forced to do now.

Comment: Central Meta dupe: [Support showing image in original size in overlay](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151793)

Comment: You know, sometimes those images are linked to something useful. More often on meta, but still applies. If you don't need that link for anything else, there is nothin stopping you from linking it to a full-scale version.